# How to replace a string using regex

Tags: php, regex

```
string = "(KEY)anything (KEY)anything (A)anything (KEY)anything";
```

result should be

```
string = "<p>anything</p> <p>anything</p> (A)anything <p>anything</p>";
```

Comment: What have you tried? Because as it is now, it's as if you're asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: Is the original string really html? If so, please consider an html parser.

Comment: I put the string in a var in php

Comment: How can you tell that one paragraph is over? Is it always just one word? Is it until the next `(KEY)`? Is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\(KEY\)(\w+)` with `<p>$1</p>`, or whatever the equivalent php notation is.

This assumes that the boundaries are word boundaries (anything other than 0-9A-Za-z_).

Comment: You should put \\(KEY\\)(\w+)

Comment: @faressoft - `)` does not require escaping unless preceded by an unescaped `(`. Reducing the number of \ is good, especially when they need double-escaping in string literals.

Comment: This is not generally true. Python, for example, will complain about an unbalanced parenthesis.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Thanks for the info. I assumed php would use PCRE.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\(KEY\)(\w+)/', '<p>\1</p>', $subject);
```

will work on your example.

If `anything` can be more than one word and is defined as "anything after `(KEY)` and before the next opening parenthesis", then you can use

```
$result = preg_replace('/\(KEY\)([^(]+)/', '<p>\1</p>', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to start, here is an excellent tutorial on regular expressions:
[Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

There are also nice (and free) tools to help you crafting them:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Answer (score 0):

Check out preg_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$pattern = '\(KEY\)(\w+)\s';
$replacement = '<p>$1</p>';
$string = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$string);
```

Something like that should work.